# JavaScript: Dynamically build a condition by fetching properties/values of an array with one object

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object, if-statement

**I am trying to make a script which**

1. Gets the current URL (url1 variable in the example) which contains params/values and which can be entirely different each time - OK
2. I extract both params and values and create an object from them with keys/values - OK
3. I build a condition for later use, dynamically which does not expect a certain number of pairs, so it gets built from whatever it finds in the object - **NOT OK**

.

```
let url1 = 'http://localhost/myproject/results?id=0001&area=eiffel+tower&city=Paris&whatever=else';

function URLToArray(url) {
    var request = {};
    var pairs = url.substring(url.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&');
    for (var i = 0; i < pairs.length; i++) {
        if(!pairs[i])
            continue;
        var pair = pairs[i].split('=');
        request[decodeURIComponent(pair[0])] = decodeURIComponent(pair[1]);
     }
     console.log(request); // { id: '0001', area: 'eiffel+tower', city: 'Paris', whatever: 'else' }
     return(request);
}

let paramsObj = URLToArray(url1);

console.log(paramsObj)  // { id: '0001', area: 'eiffel+tower', city: 'Paris', whatever: 'else' }

// Step 3 below, where the issue is and I expect
// id === '0001' && area === 'eiffel+tower' && city === 'Paris' && something === 'else'

paramsObj.forEach((item) => {
  let condition = '';
  let keys = Object.keys(item);
  keys.map((k) => {
    if (condition) {
      condition += ` && ${k} === '${item[k]}'`
} else {
  condition = `${k} === '${item[k]}'`
    }

  })
  console.log(condition);
})
```

**Outputs**

`paramsObj.forEach((item) => { TypeError: paramsObj.forEach is not a function at Object.<anonymous>`

**Expected** on `console.log(condition)`

`id === '0001' && area === 'eiffel+tower' && city === 'Paris' && whatever === 'else'`

**Note**: if the object was inside `[ ]` brackets, the output would somehow be the expected one. However `URLToArray(url)` outputs object without brackets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ForEach method is an array method and you're trying to use it on an object, you should probably just create a function that takes in an object as one of its parameters.

```js
function ProcessItem(item) {
  let condition = '';
  let keys = Object.keys(item);
  keys.map((k) => {
    if (condition) {
      condition += ` && ${k} === '${item[k]}'`
    } else {
      condition = `${k} === '${item[k]}'`
    }

  })
  console.log(condition);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following.

```js
var url1 = 'http://localhost/myproject/results?id=0001&area=eiffel%20tower&city=Paris&whatever=else';

function getQueryFromURL(u) {
  var r = {};
  var parts;
  if (u.indexOf("?") > -1) {
    parts = u.substr(u.indexOf("?") + 1).split("&");
    $.each(parts, function(i, v) {
      r[v.split("=")[0]] = decodeURI(v.split("=")[1]);
    });
  }
  return r;
}

function objJoin(o, a, b) {
  var r = "";
  var arr;
  $.each(o, function(k, v) {
    if (r.length == 0) {
      r += [k, a, v].join(" ");
    } else {
      r += " " + [b, k, a, v].join(" ");
    }
  });
  return r;
}

let paramsObj = getQueryFromURL(url1);

console.log(paramsObj);

console.log(objJoin(paramsObj, "===", "&&"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

This does not do anything vastly different, it just makes a bit better use of the tools at hand to get the same result.

Answer (score 0):

The `URLToArray()` returns an object and not an array. You cannot use `forEach` on an instance of an object.

Instead, you may want to iterate over keys, like the following:

```js
Object.keys(paramsObj).forEach((key) => {
  const value = paramsObj[key];
  let condition = '';
  if (condition) {
    condition += ` && ${key} == ${value}`;
  } else {
    condition = `${key} == ${value}`;
  }
);
```

Comment: I think it misses an } before the last ), but for some reason when is added, the iteration resets the condition, each time and also does not add the `&` operator. `console.log(condition)` after `else { ... }`, I get `id == 0001
area == eiffel+tower
city == Paris
something == else`